# Birt Report Engine Command Line (genReport.sh) - How to output in Excel?

Tags: birt

I see the web viewer has this option but I don't see an option in genReport.sh.  Does anyone know?  Surely it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script `genReport.sh` should accept `-f XLS` option for rendering Excel output. Take a look at this [birt exchange post](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/11788-how-to-generate-xml-with-report-engine-command-line/page__view__findpost__p__36425) describing more formats available in genReport.